# bash/awk append next line if the columns is less than 4

Tags: bash, awk, append

I would like to do the following but dont know how to to this in awk. I need to append the next line if the number of columns are less than 4 (so that it matches the lines with 8 columns)

```
aaa2 17 79285137 bbb3 0.23 A X 5
aaa2 17 79287477 
aaa2 1 F F 5 
aaa2 17 79291434 bbb33 1 G X 5
aaa2 17 79292215 bcs23 1 Q X 5
aaa22 4 4201745 
aaa22 1 C C 5
....
```

to

```
aaa2 17 79285137 bbb3 0.23 A X 5
aaa2 17 79287477 aaa2 1 F F 5 
aaa2 17 79291434 bbb33 1 G X 5
aaa2 17 79292215 bcs23 1 Q X 5
aaa22 4 4201745  aaa22 1 C C 5
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit: I restored the ealier versions otherwise it will be difficult to follow..)

One more:

```
awk '{ORS=NF<4?x:RS}1' file
```

---

The above can be used if no field separator is needed between rejoined sentence parts. Here is one that would introduce a space:

```
awk 'ORS=NF<4?FS:RS' file
```

---

Even though the above options will work for OP's sample input, they would fail if the line that needs to be joined has fewer than 4 fields (for instance a total of lines with 2 x 3 fields that need to be joined to one line with 6 fields, which is not the case with the sample above)

That is why I added this option:

```
awk 'NF<4{getline $(NF+1)}1' file
```

---

I had a look at the Dimitre's link to Ed Morton's post but I think that in this case there are no real `getline` caveats that would apply. The fact that NF does not get updated is not problem for this application. Normally I would test success of a getline but I left that out here, because if in the hypthetical situation there would be fewer than 3 fields on the last line then the input file would be broken to begin with and none of the solutions here would provide a 100% correct answer.

Comment: +1 for the simplest, most awk-ish solution but replace `x` with `FS`.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea that's what you were using `x` for, I assumed it was leftover from a previous iteration of your script where you were setting `x` and had just forgot to change it in this iteration.. Maybe a null string `""` would be clearer in that context?

Comment: @EdMorton: Perhaps you are right. I like using `x` because it is like crossing out something. Anyway, I find out my earlier suggestion was wrong, because it depends on the number of fields in the next line, which only happens to be more than 4 in this example. So I changed it for to a better version...

Comment: IMHO what you had originally was ideal and what you have now is not a good solution, sorry. Your original solution did exactly what the OP asked for "I need to append the next line if the number of columns are less than 4" but this new one won't necessarily do that as it will ignore the number of fields on every 2nd line that has less than 4. It also introduces all the getline caveats.

Comment: @EdMorton: It will only issue a getline if the number of fields is less than 4, so not on every 2nd line, so  I think it does what the OP asked, no? The previous one would go wrong if the next line would happen to have fewer than 4 fields... What getline caveats are you driving at?

Comment: See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/_ia_n96_lFg/nBXlUB2XFVAJ).

Comment: The line you "getline" will bypass the NF<4 test so if that line had less than 4 fields then you wouldn't append the next line to it which violates the requirement I mentioned. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline for most getline caveats.

Answer (score 3):

try this line:

```
awk 'NF<4{printf "%s", $0;next}1' file
```

Comment: Logic is good but misses a bit of allignment.Its better to add a space after %s `"%s "` to give a proper allignment

Comment: @sarathi adding space doesn't help to get better alignment. for example if the $NF, very short. I would do a `awk....|column -t` to gain alignment.

Answer (score 1):

This awk will work for you:

```
awk '{if (pre!="") {print pre $0; pre=""} else if (NF>=4) print; else pre=$0}' in.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if(NF<4){x=$0;f=1;next}if(f){$0=x" "$0;f=0};print}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> awk '{if(NF<4){x=$0;f=1;next}if(f){$0=x" "$0;f=0};print}' temp
aaa2 17 79285137 bbb3 0.23 A X 5
aaa2 17 79287477  aaa2 1 F F 5 
aaa2 17 79291434 bbb33 1 G X 5
aaa2 17 79292215 bcs23 1 Q X 5
aaa22 4 4201745  aaa22 1 C C 5
>
```